# Why do I see hollows in a cycles renderer after solidify & shrinkwrap?

Tags: modeling

I'm worried about result at a viewport. I see hoolows at pants then I turn on cycles renderer, but everything is ok at each other mode. My steps before:

1. added a cube. name as "Pants"
2. added a boolean modifier with an intersection (cube with body). apply
3. shrinkwrap & solidify.

[image]

Comment: Might be inverted normals causing the solidify to got the other way around on this specific area. go into edit mode, select everything with A and press SHIFT N to recalculate the normals

Comment: @Gorgious sorry. not working for me (( tnx for response